# My site auto redirect to unwanted site in mobile

Tags: redirect, mobile, joomla

I use `JA_Rasite` template for my site:[www.nll.com.vn](http://www.nll.com.vn). But now when I visit my site on mobie it auto redirect to random(unwanted) site. Sometime it is porn site, sometime is adverting site. Anyone have a solution to fix this problems?

Comment: You got hacked. Your site needs a good audit

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that it depends on the template you are using, most probably it's got hacked and the first thing to do is to reinstall the original JA_Rasite template package.

Of course you'd better check and secure your site to prevent further attacks.